# How to display image in C++/CLI using a handle

Tags: c#, wpf, camera, c++-cli, handle

I have a mixed application that uses C# with WPF for the general app usage (UI and etc.) and C++/CLI for getting and processing a picture from a camera.

I am using a `WindowsFormsHost` with a `Panel` inside it in WPF so I can get the `Panel` `handle` and pass it to the C++/CLI code, and then use this `handle` to show the camera frame that was captured.

**How can I show this camera frame in the panel, using the `handle` in C++/CLI?**

I know it's possible because one of the camera's APIs have a C function that automatically shows the camera image in the `Panel` if I pass it's `Handle`. Unfortunately I can't use this API in this application because it shows the raw camera image, and I want to show the processed image.

Comment: Why don't you pass the image to the C# code and show it in a more conventional way? Like a WPF `BitmapSource` for instance?

Comment: Because if I operate the camera in a high fps it can have a high performance impact.... So displaying it in c++ I get a lot of performance